# How to define custom request scope just in user defined classes

Tags: java, spring, scope

I have two web application. In first one there are running web services and I have there some context in request scope:

```
<bean class="cz.isvs.ais3.context.request.RequestContextImpl" scope="request">
    <aop:scoped-proxy proxy-target-class="true"/>
</bean>
```

In second application there are running some task every minute and request scope is replaced by fake one to use same context:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomScopeConfigurer">
    <property name="scopes">
        <map>
            <entry key="request">
                <bean class="org.springframework.context.support.SimpleThreadScope" />
            </entry>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And now task is how to refactor this two applications into one. Problem is how to solve this scope problem. I cant add fake scope and without it tasks are not working. Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a composite scope that would delegate its work `RequestScope` if request is present, or to `SimpleThreadScope` otherwise:

```
public class CompositeRequestScope implements Scope {
    private final Scope requestScope = new RequestScope();
    private final Scope fallbackScope = new SimpleThreadScope();

    public Object get(String name, ObjectFactory<?> objectFactory) {
        return activeScope().get(name, objectFactory);
    }

    ...

    private Scope activeScope() {
        if (RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes() != null) {
            return requestScope;    
        } else {
            return fallbackScope;
        }
    }
}
```

and register it using `CustomScopeConfigurer`.

Though I'm not sure how to replace the build-in `request` scope, perhaps you'll need to register it under different name.